# Add values at the given position in a JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I'm using java, json.simple.JSONObject. I have a json object inside which I have a json array. I want to add empty values in a given postion

```
{"rows_map":{"2":["test1a","2011-12-08 18:13:50.6"],"1":["test2","2011-12-07 11:51:11.237"]}
```

Suppose i want to add values at second position

```
{"rows_map":{"2":["test1a","","2011-12-08 18:13:50.6"],"1":["test2","","2011-12-07 11:51:11.237"]}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put the value by passing it's position for example

```
jsonarr.put(1,"");
```

check here for more http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: put() method replaces existent object, not inserts a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the empty values into your array *before* you encode it!